# Remove nested object in React State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested, state, nested-object

In React I have some filters in a state:

```
this.state {
   filters: [countries: {parameterName: 'country', value: 'England'}, 
                        {parameterName: 'country', value: 'Greenland'}]
}
```

In an onClick-Handler function I receive one of these objects:

```
removeFilter(filter) {     
        console.log('remove->', filter);
        // outputs: {value: 'England', parameterName: 'country'} 
}
```

Is there a way to remove that object from my state using setState?
I currently try using 'find' to get the object inside the state itself but I'm not sure how to remove it:

```
let found ? this.state.filters[filter.parameterName].find(element => element.value === filter.value))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a react state management question, so you want to avoid mutation, by that I mean that you don't want to manipulate the original array object. So you want to create a new array excluding the one that you want to remove. Like:

const newFilter = countryFilter.filter(f => f.value !== filter.value);

then you want to keep constructing the new state object, and place this array where it belongs on the state object.

I think the state object you pasted in your question is not correct, so I am not trying to guess the correct structure of it.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense, so I actually got it to work by creating a new array, thanks :)